# How many unique combinations you can have when pairing 17 designs into a 7 set?

Tags: combinatorics

Following situation: You have 17 designs for a packing box and you want to create a set where you put 7 of them into box. The sort is not important, but the set has to be unique and no double designs in it.

Example:

17 Designs = Letters from A - Q where A = 1 and Q = 17

First possible Set would be: A B C D E F G
Second: H I J K L M N
Third: A Q C D E B H

Following is not allowed: A B C D E E F ( duplicate E )
Following is not allowed: A B C D E F G ( Because it's already existing at the "First possible Set" and it would be against the "It has to be unique" rule )

So how many combinations of them I can get? I also would like to understand how I should approach to get the answer.

My current idea would be something like: 17 ^ 7 = 410338673, but I am not really sure about it. I used `exponentiation` Tag, because I think this is the right way.

**EDIT**

So from a facebook source, the solution seems to be: 19448
And following comment exists: "17!/((17-7)!*7!)"

What does `!` mean and is this way and result correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ${17 \choose 7}$.

For a set of $n$ elements, the number $k$-element subsets it has is ${n \choose k}$.

Comment: And in case OP has no idea what $n\choose k$ means, the search term is "binomial coefficient".

Comment: Which is also, for reference, equal to $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ as credited to the "Facebook source" above. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient also.

Comment: So this comment seems to be the right thing, also the comments helped me alot, because I really never heard of this and now I am going further to reading, understand and reconstruct the solution. Thanks all, also Thanks at @Remember me for helping

Comment: Also, the ! is the factorial - in brief, the product $n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1)$ - see more about factorials at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial as well for a proper formal definition and examples.

Answer (score 0):

So first thing:

1) Repetition is not allowed

2) The order here is not important(note this point). That is I can put ABCDEFG first and then put HIJKLMN , Even if i put the latter one first it will not make a difference. So in that case the number of choices will $$\binom{17}{7}$$

Now if order had caused a difference then it would have been 
$$P^{17}_7$$ where $P$ denotes the permutation.